# Does every essential subsurface of a surface contain a smooth curve?

Tags: analysis, differential-topology, surfaces

Given a closed surface $S,$ does every essential subsurface contain a smooth curve? (curve = essential, simple, closed in the original surface) (essential subsurface = all boundary components are essential and curves)

The "worst case scenario", I'd imagine, is an annular subsurface where both boundary components are nowhere smooth. Without loss of generality, the annulus is $\epsilon-$thick.

I imagine the answer is yes, simply because there's enough "wiggle room". That's clearly not a proof, so I have some ideas/restatements below.

---

The above question is equivalent to: Can every continuous map $u:S^1\to \Sigma$ be approximated by a smooth map?

I'm familiar with some results in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ but I don't know how to apply them (or how to reduce the problem to a map that sends the circle to $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Many thanks!

Comment: Please, explain what do you mean by a "curve" and an "essential subsurface." By the way, the two questions are not equivalent (although, they have the same, positive, answer - provided that "essential" mean $\pi_1$-injective and noncontractibe  and $S$ is not a sphere or projective plane, and "curve" means a "closed curve").

Comment: @MoisheKohan
Thanks, updated to answer your questions! You interpreted everything as I intended though.
Hmmm why are these not equivalent? (in this case, I take "these" to be: "smooth curve in an annular subsurface" and "approximating a continuous curve using a smooth curve")